# Bathrom LED Exhaust fan. LEDs are dimming and some do not light

Tags: bathroom, repair, light

[image: Ceiling Bathroom Fan & LED Light]Bathroom ceiling light has stopped lighting fully. Some LEDs still light some and some do not light at all. I might be inside the 5 year warranty (if I can find the receipt), but I want to know if this is salvageable. Can I replace the strip light or solder it or replace the driver to get them all lit again?

Comment: Can you unscrew it and see what the back side looks like?